# htaccess subdomain rewrite keep www

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've set up wildcard domains locally for testing on .dev

I'm trying to rewrite the following URL:

```
http://location.domain.dev/
```

to

```
http://www.domain.dev/site/location
```

I would like any requests with `www` in the subdomain to always go to www.domain.dev but if any request is made to location.domain.dev, I would like to keep that request in the address bar (i.e i dont want people to see the underlying change)

I currently have the following in my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.dev
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.dev/site/%1 [QSA,NC]

  # Removes index.php
  RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty close. In order to not redirect the browser (causing the address bar to change) you need to get rid of the `http://domain.dev` part of the rewrite rule's target:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site/%1/$1 [QSA,NC]
```

assuming that both ***.domain.dev** and **www.domain.dev** have the same document root. If they're different, you may have to enable mod_proxy and add a `P` flag so that the request gets proxied instead of redirecting the browser:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.dev/site/%1/$1 [QSA,NC,P]
```

Comment: Thanks Jon, How do I enable mod_proxy? Can I do this via .htaccess?

I've added in your code, however, I dont seem to be going to the correct place after the redirect.

Comment: @HerbageOnion it's turned on via server config (LoadModule), if it isn't already on. What do you mean by not going to the correct place after the redirect? Try adding the `/$1`'s to the end of the targets.

Comment: okay, i just checked the httpd.cong and mod_proxy is enabled. I used your second rule and now its working. The last problem is if I visit http://www.domain.dev/ (with the www) it attempts to go to http://domain.dev/location/www, how do I stop the rewrite from doing this?

Comment: @HerbageOnion Add a `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]` above the other rewrite condition.

Comment: ah! I was doing it below! :) awesome, one last question, how would I redirect non-www or empty subdomains to www?